# jquery slim scroll bar config not working

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

I am using `jQuery SlimScroll`, my config not working.

i would like to

1. show the `scrollbar` and `rail` always.
2. I want to start my scroll from the bottom.
3. once the set to bottom i would like to trigger a function.

js on init:

```
$(container).slimScroll({
    width: '300px',
    size: '10px',
    position: 'right',
    color: '#ffcc00',
    alwaysVisible: true, //not working
    distance: '20px',
    start: 'bottom', //not working
    railVisible: true,
    railColor: '#222',
    railOpacity: 0.3,
    wheelStep: 10,
    allowPageScroll: false,
    disableFadeOut: false
});

$(container).slimScroll().
bind('slimscroll', function(e, pos){
    if(pos == 'bottom') {
        $.event.trigger('bottomReached');
    }
});
```

how to config this all?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/25/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code with jQuery SlimScroll doesnt work because the content div is empty. All works correctly if you add enough text to it.

*For example:*

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="content">

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc

     </div>
</div>
```